# Timer is starting late, hence shows the time which is a second late then actual time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a timer. But it starts a second late.I mean, i am clocking a time according to the timer. But the time in the clock, which updates through timer, is one second less then the actual time elapsed. The timer starts off a second late. How to set my timer to start at right time to show actual time? this is the code inside tick event:

```
 if (currentState == play)
 {
     m_StatusLabel.Text = String.Format("Playing {0} ", format(timeCounter));
     timeCounter++;
 }
```

Here timeCounter is updating with each second.

Comment: Do you have any code you can post?

Comment: and what's the initial delay set to?

Comment: What clock are you talking about ? Post more code please.

Comment: no delay set. timer interval is 1000 millisecond. You can consider timer counter as the clock as of now.

Answer (score 3):

Standard `System.Windows.Forms` timers give no guarantees about 'metronome quality'. For that, you would need either a `Systems.Threading.Timer` or a `System.Timer`.

Ref: [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are no timers available that will gaurantee true-time accuracy, not even System.Threading.Timer can do that.  For example, when you ask Threading.Timer to fire in 30ms, it might actually take 40ms or 200ms. Or if you ask for 1 second, it might fire in 1.01 seconds.  In won't take long before your time is inaccurate.

The reason for this is that the timer makes the callback thread schedulable, but it still takes time for the thread scheduler to actually call the thread.  Various operations the system is performing can delay that callback.

Comment: Better to ask the system the time repeatedly via `DateTime.Now,` rather than trying to increment time yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows timer makes only one guarantee: it won't fire before the timeout interval elapses. Specifically, a thread will never receive a timer event while there are messages in its message queue.

Consequently you can't use timers to implement a clock. If you want to update a status message to show how long something has been playing, then you could try this: record the start time, and when your timer ticks get the current time, subtract the start time, and dislay the difference. Your status message won't be updated exactly every second, but when it is updated it will be correct.

Comment: I have to display the status message every second.

Comment: You might have a few options: (1) Set your timer interval to less than one second, so that if you miss one that's OK. (2) Put your timer on a worker thread, not the main UI thread. The worker thread's queue will usually be empty and so it will receive the timer events more reliably. When the worker thread gets the timer message, post a message of your own to the UI thread - that will still be subject to queueing, but unlike a real timer message it won't have to wait until the UI thread's queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

#### Show a number 1 greater:

```
if (currentState == play)
     m_StatusLabel.Text = String.Format("Playing {0} ",
                                        format(++timeCounter) );
```

NOTE

Please consider the reason of those who suggested displaying the elapsed time as *current time - start time*.  That is the way this is usually done.  It is  more accurate; a timer can be irregular on a busy system.  It is still possible to update the displayed value every second. Pseudo code here for `now()`. This requires acquiring  current time and performing a time difference.

```
if (currentState == play)
     m_StatusLabel.Text = String.Format("Playing {0} ",
                                  format( (now() - start)/1000 );
```

See Also:
1. [DateTime.Subtraction](http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1040/time-milliseconds-Windows.htm)
2. [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)